# How do I batch-change the case of words in a Document with Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a document with a scientific text. Some words (author's names etc.) are in small caps, but they need to be hard-coded all-small-caps, because the book designer asks for them that way and there is less to go wrong.

This works when manually selecting the words and changing the case via the menu to lower case. However I can't find a way to do this with all occurrences of small caps in a document. I can search for them with find/replace, but I can't change the case.

Does anyone know a way to do this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please clarify; the you need to find all occurrences of **small caps** and change them to **lower case**? You also wrote "*they need to be hard-coded all-small-caps*". What does that mean?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I meant to say, that they need to be lower case small caps as opposed to the OpenType "all small caps" option, that displays all small caps while keeping the encoding of the Upper Case Letters. I want to avoid that someone accidentally returns them to "normal" small caps. 

For this I want to find all instances of small caps and turn them to lower case.